# How to loop over a functionalized plot in R?

Tags: r, function, loops

This is my dataset:

```
df_table <- data.frame(user = c("User1", "User2", "User3"), opened_dates = c("2021-07-01", "2021-08-02", "2021-09-03"), num_active_users = c(5, 18, 11))
```

I have the following function that I use to create a plot for all the users in my dataset.

```
daily_active_users <- function(data, user, plot_color = "blue") {
ggplot(data, aes(x = opened_dates, y = num_active_users, fill = plot_color)) + 
geom_col() + 
theme(legend.position = "none") +
labs(title = paste0(user, ": Daily # Active Users"), y = "# Active Users")}
```

Currently I have to manually specify the user to run plots for each one as so

```
daily_active_users(df_table, "User1", plot_color = "blue")
```

I want a way to loop over all the users without having to manually do so like I am doing above. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `lapply(df_table%>% distinct(user)%>%pull(user), function(x) daily_active_users(df_table, x))` will give you your plots in a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

With tidyverse's `purrr::map()` and a little modification to the order of your function you could try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df_table <- data.frame(user = c("User1", "User2", "User3"), opened_dates = c("2021-07-01", "2021-08-02", "2021-09-03"), num_active_users = c(5, 18, 11))

# Note that I switched the order of the parameters "user" and "data"
daily_active_users <- function(user, data, plot_color = "blue") {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = opened_dates, y = num_active_users)) + 
    geom_col(fill = plot_color) + # Note that I moved plot_color here, to actually get the plot in the color you request.
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(title = paste0(user, ": Daily # Active Users"), y = "# Active Users")}

list_of_figures <- 
  map(.x = df_table$user, 
      .f = daily_active_users, 
      data = df_table)

# Plot the list of figures
list_of_figures[[1]]/list_of_figures[[2]]/list_of_figures[[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following @Limey's comment above, you could use `lapply()`. It may be helpful to move the `user` parameter to the first parameter to avoid having to use `function(x)`. So:

```r
df_table <- data.frame(user = c("User1", "User2", "User3"), opened_dates = c("2021-07-01", "2021-08-02", "2021-09-03"), num_active_users = c(5, 18, 11))

daily_active_users <- function(user, data, plot_color = "blue") {
    ggplot(data,
           aes(x = opened_dates, y = num_active_users, fill = plot_color)
    ) + 
    geom_col() + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    labs(
        title = paste0(user, ": Daily # Active Users"),
        y = "# Active Users")
}
users <- df_table %>% distinct(user) %>% pull(user)
plts <- lapply(users, daily_active_users, df_table) %>%
    setNames(users)
```

Then you can refer to each plot using `plts[[<user>]]`, e.g.:

```r
plts[["User2"]]
```